# Find out if the current machine is on aws in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I have a python script that runs on aws machines, as well as on other machines.
The functionality of the script depends on whether or not it is on AWS.

Is there a way to programmatically discover whether or not it runs on AWS? (maybe using boto?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do that strictly using boto, you could do:

```
import boto.utils
md = boto.utils.get_instance_metadata(timeout=.1, num_retries=0)
```

The `timeout` specifies the how long the HTTP client will wait for a response before timing out.  The `num_retries` parameter controls how many times the client will retry the request before giving up and returning and empty dictionary.

Comment: FYI, older versions of boto (e.g. `python-boto` v2.2.2 on Ubuntu Precise) don't support the `timeout` and `num_retries` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily use the AWS SDK and check for instance id. 
beside of that, you can check the aws ip ranges - check out this link
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, using:

```
try:
    instance_id_resp = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id')
    is_on_aws = True
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    is_on_awas = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the above, and when *not* running on Amazon I had troubles accessing 169.254.169.254. Maybe it has something to do with the fact I'm outside the US.

In any case, here's a piece of code that worked for me:

```
def running_on_amazon():
  import urllib2
  import socket

  # I'm using curlmyip.com, but there are other websites that provide the same service 
  ip_finder_addr = "http://curlmyip.com" 
  f = urllib2.urlopen(ip_finder_addr)
  my_ip = f.read(100).strip()
  host_addr = socket.gethostbyaddr(my_ip)

  my_public_name = host_addr[0]
  amazon = (my_public_name.find("aws") >=0 )
  return amazon # returns a boolean value.
```